# React i18next translation issue with the state value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-i18next

I'm using i18next translation in my React project, but I have a problem with below code, translated value appears when the app open for the first time, but the text converts to the default language when the app refreshes

```
const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: t('abcPage') },
    { key: 'second', title: t('defPage') },
  ]);
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you show the complete file ? What is "translated value" ? Where does it appears (show us render function / component return statement) ? What is "the text" ? Can you also show the translation file it is using ?

Comment: are you using some i18next backend plugin? If so you need to make sure you're not calling t() before i18next is ready: https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense